# Configuring Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Device for AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I tried the following

https://mega.co.nz/#!XYZzGJyD!YOD4HvIjX5mGm1yzvCxvUDOoazRau73xYYtEH_5-qM4

but when I click on "Create Device" button, nothing appears, no error messages, nothing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK must be installed first before the Galaxy Tab emulator can be added as an Android Virtual Device (AVD). The AVD Manager allows you to install the Galaxy Tab add on. To install and run the Galaxy Tab add on, perform the following steps [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000042)

Comment: It's outdated. It's from 2011, the window "Android SDK and AVD Manager" do not exist anymore. They are separeted now in "SDK Manager" and "AVD Manager" and in "SDK Manager" do not exist the "Thirty Party Add-ons"

Comment: did you tried [this](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095)?
I use this avd. works fine. I assume your setup is the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I did. But nothing happens.